# Installed Chrome and 2 Portable Chrome (paf format) - can open alongside simultaneously. Is it really official?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, portable

Installed Chrome and 2 Portable Chrome (paf format) - can open alongside simultaneously. Is it really official?

In any other browser, I cannot do this even in Chrome. But I just tried it now, it works with no problem.

Is it really okay, or am I risking something? Is it really working portably (my portable browsers) even if I run it alongside with Standard Installed Chrome, nothing on the Portable Browser will be left behind the host pc?

Or it might get into profile collision if I continue this?

Please help clarify things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand how portable apps work, whatever removable media you installed it onto will typically setup program / files locally on that device. This would be separate from the program files located on the C: drive of the PC you're working on. I don't think you have much to worry about, if anything you may have to deal with an occasional crash because of incompatibilities, but nothing crazy

Comment: Is what official?  The portable version of Chrome does not store the user profile on the host system it stores it on the storage device itself as one might expect.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I know that portable version of chrome stores data on the storage device. I'm asking what might happen opening all those alongside simultaneously: Installed Chrome and multiple Portable Chromes at the same time? Because you know, in Firefox, Opera, and any other browsers, you cannot do that, it won't allow you, or else, the profiles will collide.

Comment: They are seperate processes.  Portable versions of those applications do allow what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge, it is perfectly safe to open the two side by side.  The PAF instance runs within its own "sandbox" or "container" with access only to its own environment - thats the whole idea of portable apps.

I have just launched chrome portable and regular chrome on my pc and then browsed a website, added a favourite, signed into facebook (setting a cookie) and deleted my browsing history on the portable version as well as replying to your other question on incognito mode.  None of these changes carried through to the desktop version of chrome.

This leads me to believe that although it is not officially supported by Google, it is perfectly ok to do.

Comment: Thanks again Farez87. I have trying to do this for months, all browser did not allow it, Firefox, Opera, PaleMoon and even Chrome. Now I just tried it with Chrome and it's working. However, Firefox and the rest still won't allow it. It only calls the previously opened instance, just like opening a new tab or window of the previous opened instance. I hope u get what I mean. Do you think it will continue to be okay or I might have collide my portable profiles with the Installed one if I continue. I have a feeling im just lucky now. Now only, u know. :-)